# Adjustbox ate my newlines

Tags: graphics, adjustbox

Apologies for the long MWE. Wanted to understand what I was doing wrong here. Trying to shrink this as part of a longer exercise in producing some slides. (This is the legend for a graphic referenced elsewhere on the site). Why is adjustbox doing this? How can I stop it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage{preamble}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1in,top=2in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{kernelfbox}{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes,arrows,chains,mindmap,trees,backgrounds}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1in}\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1in}


\definecolor{ablue1}{RGB}{0,79,182}
\definecolor{agrey1}{RGB}{164,174,181}
\definecolor{ablue2}{RGB}{0,169,224}
\definecolor{agrey2}{RGB}{81,98,111}
\definecolor{ablue3}{RGB}{114,199,231}
\definecolor{agreen1}{RGB}{89,179,55}
\definecolor{ayellow1}{RGB}{255,184,28}
\definecolor{agreen2}{RGB}{39,89,55}
\definecolor{ablue4}{RGB}{194,222,234}
\definecolor{agreen3}{RGB}{0,121,52}
\definecolor{agreen4}{RGB}{169,220,146}
\definecolor{aorange}{RGB}{229,114,0}
\definecolor{ayellow2}{RGB}{248,234,142}

\def\Mgt{\textcolor{agrey2}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Inveq{\textcolor{ayellow1}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Invfi{\textcolor{ayellow2}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Rel{\textcolor{agreen1}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Rem{\textcolor{ablue2}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Adm{\textcolor{aorange}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Rsk{\textcolor{agrey1}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Bzd{\textcolor{ablue4}{\Gentsroom}}
\def\Sup{\textcolor{agreen3}{\Gentsroom}}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{2}[0,0](0,-2)
\begin{minipage}[r][0.5\textheight][b]{0.25\paperwidth}
\adjustbox{scale={0.75}}{
{\Mgt} {\scriptsize Msldfk} \par 
{\Bzd} {\scriptsize Bsadlfsj} \newline
{\Rsk} {\scriptsize Rwelj} \tabularnewline
{\Rem} {\scriptsize Rweld} \\
{\Adm} {\scriptsize Afddsf} \\
{\Rel} {\scriptsize Refsdfd} \\
{\Invfi} {\scriptsize Fikjlkjklj} \\
{\Inveq} {\scriptsize Ejknsdfd}\\
{\Sup} {\scriptsize Support}\\
}
\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\adjustbox` and the basically identical `adjustbox` environment enfore the so called *restricted horizontal mode* for the content. In this mode you can't have line breaks. You need to wrap the content into a paragraph building element, like `\parbox`, `minipage` or `varwidth`. The last two are also provided as options to `\adjustbox` and `{adjustbox}`. See the manual for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot answer *why* it ignores newline commands (there must be a good reason!) but I can tell you *how* to avoid it.

Give `adjustbox` the `minipage` option. **EDIT** and in this case you can omit the outer `minipage` you used, and give all the options to `adjustbox` option. In your example:

```
\begin{textblock}{2}[0,0](0,-2)
\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=[r][0.5\textheight][b]{0.25\paperwidth},scale={0.75}}{
{\Mgt} {\scriptsize Msldfk} \\
{\Bzd} {\scriptsize Bsadlfsj} \\
{\Rsk} {\scriptsize Rwelj} \\
{\Rem} {\scriptsize Rweld} \\
{\Adm} {\scriptsize Afddsf} \\
{\Rel} {\scriptsize Refsdfd} \\
{\Invfi} {\scriptsize Fikjlkjklj} \\
{\Inveq} {\scriptsize Ejknsdfd}\\
{\Sup} {\scriptsize Support}
}
\end{textblock}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: presumably adjustbox defaults to being a horizontal (LR) box like mbox or fbox, which would similarly be single line.

Comment: @JLDiaz that was worth it just for the time it will save me typing the minipage thing in over and over again.. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed, it uses restricted horizontal mode and therefore no line breaks work. You need to use the `minipage` option as shown here or the similar, but easier `varwidth=<max width>` option.